# Clear: both for divs => 1050px doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css

I wrote a script that generates text sections by specifying the width, height, background and color of the text. According to my idea, divs that have less than 1050 pixels should get `float: left`, while larger float do not hold.

I would like to mention that before everything worked as it should, I do not know if I have crashes somewhere with a slight refactoring code. Try to generate three divs in a row

E.g:

```
First div: width: 525, height: 250, background: eaeaea, color: 000
Second div: width: 525, height: 250, background: c0c0c0, color: fff
Third div: width: 1050, height: 400, background: 222222, color: fff
```

And see what happens, the first two elements should be next to each other, and the third underneath, and it happens that the third generated div covers the previous two - why?

```js
$("#add_section").on("click", function() {
    var sectionid = $(".sekcja").length;
    var sectionwidth = prompt("Section width");
    var sectionheight = prompt("Section height");
    var bg = prompt("BG color");
    var sectioncolor = prompt("Text color");
    $("#new_section").append('<div class="sekcja" style="width: ' + sectionwidth + 'px; min-height: ' + sectionheight + 'px; background: #' + bg + '; color: #' + sectioncolor + ';"><button type="button" class="add_text">Add text</button><input type="hidden" name="section[' + sectionid + '][sectionwidth]" value="' + sectionwidth + '" /> <input type="hidden" name="section[' + sectionid + '][sectionheight]" value="' + sectionheight + '" /> <input type="hidden" name="section[' + sectionid + '][bg]" value="' + bg + '" /> <input type="hidden" name="section[' + sectionid + '][sectioncolor]" class="sectioncolor" value="' + sectioncolor + '" /> <input type="hidden" class="sectionid" name="sectionid" value="' + sectionid + '" /></div>');
        if ($(".sekcja").length > 0) {
            $("#default-section").css("display", "none");
        }
              
        if (sectionwidth < 1050) {
            $(".sekcja").css("float", "left");
        }
    });

    $("#new_section").on("click", ".add_text", function() {
        var sectionid = $(this).nextAll(".sectioncolor").next().val();
        var inputid = $('.sample').length;
        var inputwidth = prompt("Input width");
        $(this).parent().append('<input type="text" class="sample" style="width: ' + inputwidth + 'px;" placeholder="Sample text..." name="section[' + sectionid + '][input][' + inputid + '][inputtext]"/><input type="hidden" name="section[' + sectionid + '][input][' + inputid + '][inputwidth]" value="' + inputwidth + '" />');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="new_section">
  <div id="default-section">Default section</div>
</div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<button type="button" id="add_section">Add section</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add overflow: hidden to every div.sekcja element. Without it the div elements overlay themselves by theirs content. Just try your example with the first and third elements only and you will see what is going on there.